# Cloud Services in the New Azure Preview Portal (April 2014)

Tags: azure, service, cloud, preview, portal

In the new Azure portal Preview (April 2014), I cannot find the existing cloud services that I can see in the old portal. In the new Browse menu there is a list of elements such as databases, websites ... etc. .. but no cloud services. So where are the cloud services? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Why does this have a downvote. Pretty relevant to me.

Comment: Yes, this question is relevant to me too.

Comment: Annnnnnnnnnnnnnnd it's November now...

Comment: And it's December now...

Comment: I hate to say it, but it does seem that traditional VMs have taken priority, and Cloud Services are now a second class citizen on Azure.

Comment: And February 2015 now... :D

Comment: And now its April 2015 and still nothing .......

Comment: Went to a MeetUp last week where it was hinted that they were coming, but MS has been focusing on the app side of the offering (api, logic, and market place).

Answer (score 12):

Cloud Services are not yet enabled in the new portal.  Today only a limited set of features is available while the portal is still in developer preview phase, but expect to see additional Azure features being enabled soon.  See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/preview-portal/ for information about what features are available today, or http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure/Azure-Preview-portal for a good walkthrough.